# When I try to run my code in chrome, i see the code that I have made in phpstorm and not the function that it has to do

Tags: php, xampp

I just started with php and I installed my xampp and got it running. Now I wanna run my code that I have, its a simple print function but when I try running it, I see the code appear in Chrome an not the print. this is what I have in my code: `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>` and when I try to run it I get the exact same thing on chrome
[image: Chrome code]

Comment: php engine doesn't seem to be running on your server, so you don't see its work but see the script itself.

Comment: @EugeneKapustin do I need to download like php seperatly ? because the only things that I have downloaded are PHPstorm en xampp

Comment: You need to rig up your apache web server XAMPP instance to run php. Right now it's not running the php, it's just sending the text to the browser (useless!). Your favorite search engine will produce several good tutorials if you ask for "run php on apache in XAMPP".

Comment: @hasbullah I hope you managed to handle and start php server, haven't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start apache and MySQL if you are connecting to DB on XAMPP then put your script in the htdocs folder then you can run your code by going to `http://localhost`

Another solution is by running this command to start a php server

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 index.php
```